# Costumes On Purim

Tags: purim, minhag, clothing

Why is there a Minhag to dress up in costumes on Purim?

Comment: Rabbi Orlofsky Shiur and answer: [Revealing the Identity on Purim](http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/David_Orlofsky/2006-03-14/Masks:_Revealing_Our_Identity_on_Purim/Rabbi__David_Orlofsky__Masks:_Revealing_Our_Identity_on_Purim__2006-03-14.mp3)

Comment: This article traces the etymology of when this practice started (1300's) https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/.premium-why-do-jews-dress-up-for-purim-1.5330308

Comment: link is broken :/

Comment: closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135322/what-are-the-earliest-sources-for-purim-costumes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reasons mentioned why we disguise ourselves on Purim, is to highlight the concept that even the non Jews disguised themselves, pretending to be Jews. The Megila says:

> "And many of the people of the land professed themselves to be Jewish, for the fear of the Jews had fallen upon them." ([8:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

They pretended to convert to Judaism, but didn't actually. We know this because the term used in that verse is "misyahadim," -- "Judaized," instead of "misgayarim," -- "converted." Since they masqueraded as Jews, thus the custom has arisen to masquerade ourselves on Purim, to commemorate this miracle, whereby a complete turnabout caused the Gentiles to fear us and not kill us, as they had originally planned.

Comment: Note that Rashi translates it as "converted": http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%96

Answer (score 5):

One "popular" reason is that the entire נס of Purim was hidden and seemed very natural (i.e. no Hashgacha to it / Hashem's name not mentioned in the מגילה). We too hide ourselves to symbolize this.

Answer (score 0):

The [benei Isaschar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90) says ([Adar, Maamar 9:1)](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_4683_332.pdf) that as the jewish people bowed to Nevuchadnetsar externally Hashem also acted externally by making it seem as if there was a decree to destroy them. Hence, it is a custom to dress up on Purim to externally appear like non-jews.