# What are the earliest sources for Purim costumes

Tags: minhag, purim

The topic of dressing up on Purim has been discussed on the forum, but I am looking specifically for early sources that mention the custom.

Please include specific sources - direct links are preferred.

Comment: closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/costumes-on-purim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this download source sheet](https://www.yutorah.org/download.cfm?materialID=538934) and [this issue of Halachically Speaking](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol9Issue2.pdf).

It's not mentioned in the Gemara/Midrash/Geonim. [The earliest source](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/271/Q2/) seems to be a teshuva of the [Mahari Minz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_Minz) by the 15th century. This is referenced in the [Rema OC 696:8](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3078). It's a fairly new custom, not obligatory and not everyone does it